# Взаимодействие javascript между assets в yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, assets

Сделал виджет со своим Asset в котором подключается new-widget.js

```
class newWidget {
    static init(){
        $( "#grid_column_sort ul" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
        }).disableSelection();
    };
}
```

У меня есть AppAsset в котором подключается user.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    newWidget.init();
    $(document)
        .on('pjax:complete', function() {
            newWidget.init();
        })
};
```

Виджет newWidget подключен не на всех страницах, как лучше проверить его наличие?
Или как лучше организовать их взаимодействие?

Comment: Так а зачем его как-то откуда-то инициализировать? Пусть js виджета в себе и сделает инициализацию

Comment: + еще pjax обновляет html код (виджета в том числе) и нужно опять вызывать new.Widget.init() для назначения обработчиков.

Comment: +   --- что за за плюс? к чему он?

Comment: *"pjax обновляет html код (виджета в том числе) и нужно опять вызывать new.Widget.init()"* --- значит ты написал кривой код. Делегирование вполне решает вопросы слушателей.

Comment: Да, точно, это можно решить с помощью делегирования. Но еще в init() используется jQuery UI Sortable (обновил верхнее сообщение). Если с pjax его html обновить, то его javascript перестает работать. Как можно избежать переинициализации sortable?

Comment: У pjax есть события, точно так же, как и у всяких ajax.  Можно подписаться на событие перерисовки и просто переинициализировать плагин. А может и вовсе использовать pjax тут ошибка и надо всего лишь запрашивать данные с бэка, а js 'ом распоряжаться как надо. Это уже надо смотреть полностью задачу и код

Comment: По событию pjax я и инициализирую. Обновил верхнее сообщение.

Comment: Идея виджета: сортировка и выбор нужных столбцов GridView. Подготавливаются данные для GridView, потом прогоняются через мой виджет, он их фильтрует, сортирует по настройкам и данным из таблицы профилей. Сразу готовит списки включенных и выключенных сортированных столбцов. Затем модифицированные данные поступают в GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Разорвал связи с помощью делегирования.
new-widget.js:

```
class gcs{
    static enableSortable() {
        $( "#grid_column_sort ul").sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
        }).disableSelection();
    }

    static init() {
        $(document)
            .on('mouseover', function(event) {
                if (event.target.id === 'grid_column_sort') {
                    let $grid = $("#grid_column_sort");
                    if ($grid.data('init') !== true) {
                        gcs.enableSortable();
                        $grid.data({init: true});
                    }
                }
            })
            .on('click', function(event) {
                if (event.target.id === 'hide_grid_column_sort') {
                    let elem = document.getElementById('grid_column_sort');
                    elem.hidden = !elem.hidden;
                }
            })
    }
}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    gcs.init();
})
```